# Permanently replace value in Django

Tags: python, django, replace

After extensive googling, I still havent come up with an effecient way to solve this.

Im creating a website using Django. I have a db which contains time data, more specifically dates. The value for "the present" is set to 3000-01-01 (YYYY-MM-DD) as is common practice for time-querying.

What I want to do is display a string like "Now" or "Present" or any other value instead of the date 3000-01-01. Is there some sort of global override anywhere that I can use? Seems like a waste to hard-code it in every view/template.

Cheers!

Comment: Could you add a property to the model to tweak the display of that date column and access that in templates?

Comment: Looks like you can use a *template* filter, or you could of course *override* the field (so make a `NowDateField` that handles this), but I would advice against the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is rendering, I would advice against "*subclassing*" the `DateField` such that it renders `'now'` instead of the original `date(..)` object: it will make calculations in the model layer more cumbersome.

Probably a good way to deal with this is implementing a [*template filter* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/), for example we can construct a file:

```
#  app/templatetags/nowdate.py

from django import template

register = template.Library()

PRESENT = date(3000, 1, 1)

@register.filter
def nowdate(value):
    if value == PRESENT:
        return 'present'
    return value
```

The `templatetags` directory of the `app` application, needs to contain an `__init__.py` file as well (an empty file), and the `app` of course needs to be part of the `INSTALLED_APPS` in the `settings.py`.

Then we can use it in the template like:

```
<!-- app/templates/app/some_template.html -->
{{ some_model.some_date_field|nowdate }}
```

Here we thus fetch the `some_date_field` of the `some_model` variable (this attribute is thus a `date(..)` object), and we pass it through the `nowdate` filter we have constructed such that, if it is 3000-01-01, it is replaced by the `'present'` string.

The advantage here is that if we later change our mind about what date the "present" is, we can easily change it in the template filter, furthermore we can easily extend it, for example by adding a `'past'`, `'future'`, etc.

Comment: Seems to be an elegant solution. Thanks! :)